# CartThrob customer email notification not sending unless logged in to CP

Tags: cartthrob, email, notification

This one is confusing me and I'm wondering if any CartThrob experts out there have experienced this and have a solution.

My custom email notification and admin email notifications, both triggered by the "successful transaction" event, are identical to one another, except that the "to" line for the admin email is a static email address, while the "to" line for the custom email uses the {customer_email} global variable.

If I am logged into the CP and visit my order form in another tab to run a test transaction, the transaction is completed correctly and both the admin and custom emails are received (and admin email to the static email address and the customer email to the dynamic user-entered email address).

However, if I log out of the CP and visit the form, submitting a test transaction, only the admin email notification is received.  Is there some reason that I'm missing that would cause this?  A setting somewhere in CartThrob that I have missed?  I have "User Must Be Logged In?" set to "no" and I do have a member ID for an "anonymous" user set for the "Logged Out Member ID" setting.

Comment: In the CT notification settings, have you switched on the email log to see if both emails are attempted by the system? Joe

Comment: I've turned "CP Logging enabled?" to yes. Then submitted a test order - where would i go to see the email log?

Comment: Joe, I moved your answer to a comment since it's a followup question and not a direct answer. Please feel free to post a direct answer with specific how-to instructions.

Comment: Ah sorry!!
You need to look directly in the exp_cartthrob_email_log database table. You could use phpmyadmin or equivalent to do this.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I've been having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the {customer_email} field displaying, and there is data in it when it's processed? Turn on CT Debugging and just before you submit to get the email, check this field is complete.

Comment: It's not in the template it's in the "to" email address setting as a variable. It processes correctly if I am logged into the control panel, but if I'm logged out, nothing. If i use the same email address that i used in my test on the front end in the "to" email setting, it comes through. So it's sending the email, but it's not parsing the {customer_email} variable when I'm not logged into the control panel.